# What to use instead browserHistory for react router v4 to REDIRECT after Sign In/Sign In(firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redirect, react-router-v4

I'm using firebase for sign in/sign up with React Router v4.
What can I use instead browserHistory in order to redirect user after Sign In/Up to other component?

So what to use instead

`browserHistory.push('/app');` . I tried with `<Redirect push to="/app" />`

and instead `browserHistory.replace('/signin');` I tried`<Redirect replace to="/signin" />`
but it doesn't work.

Here is part of the code:
imports and onAuthStateChanged() function

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Switch, Redirect, Route} from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { firebaseApp } from './firebase';

firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    console.log('user has singed in or up', user);

    //**** WHAT TO USE INSTEAD OF THIS?*******
    // browserHistory.push('/app');

 }
  else {
    console.log('user has signed out or still needs to sign in');

     //**** WHAT TO USE INSTEAD OF THIS?*******
    // browserHistory.replace('/signin');
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is:

`import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';`

then create const history:

`const history = createHistory();`

```
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    const { email } = user;
    history.push('/');
  }
  else {
    history.replace('/signin');
  }
})
```

and then call history on

`<Router history={history}>`

Answer (score 1):

browserHistory is no longer in `react-router-v4` The best way is to use the `withRouter` HOC then you will have access to the history prop. Technically speaking you could access it via the context but I discourage it.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Switch, Redirect, Route} from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { firebaseApp } from './firebase';

firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    console.log('user has singed in or up', user);

    //**** WHAT TO USE INSTEAD OF THIS?*******
    // browserHistory.push('/app');
    this.props.history.push('/app')

 }
  else {
    console.log('user has signed out or still needs to sign in');

     //**** WHAT TO USE INSTEAD OF THIS?*******
    // browserHistory.replace('/signin');
    this.props.history.push('/signin')
 }
})

export withRouter(yourComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. helped me alot this.